# could not convert string to float in linux Debian 11

Tags: numpy-ndarray

In DEBIAN11, I write a code for serial display on GUI to plot a graph using dev/ttyACMO but unfortunately an error occurred that string could not convert to float here is the code:

```py
import serial as sr
import matplotlib.pyplot asplt
import numpy as np

s=sr.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',115200);
plt.close('all')
plt.figure();
plt.ion();
plot.show();

data = np.array([]);
i=0



while i<100
 a=s.readline()
 a.decode()
 b = float(a[0:4])
 data = np.append(data,b);
 plt.plot(data);
 plt.pause(0.01);
 i=i+1
s.close()
```

Comment: Where exactly and what error? Please provide a [mcve] and the output it produces as part of your question. Also, add a language tag to it. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask]. BTW: Don't put semicolons everywhere.

Comment: in line (b= float (a[0:4])) , it couldn't convert string into float

Comment: Doesn't really help: Since I don't have anything attached to a serial port here, how should I know what it sends? So, what exactly is in `a`? Use `print(repr(a))` to find out. Use that to shorten your program. Also, still no language tag!